# <br /> not working in I.E

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

My code is working perfectly as desired in firefox(TEXT1 on top of TEXT2) and chrome  but not in Internet explorer.
Here is my code.Note that TEXT1 &TEXT2 replaces other html elements in my original code,just used TEXT to simplify the code. Thank you.

```
    <div style="float:left;">
     <span class="line-1">
      TEXT1
     </span><br />
     <span class="line-2">
     TEXT2
     </span>
     </div>
```

css

```
    .line-1{
    margin:3px; 
    padding:5px;    
    background:#F0F2F5; 
    float:left;
   -moz-border-radius:3px;
   -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-left:solid #B6BBC3 1px;
    border-right:solid #B6BBC3 1px;
    border-top:solid #B6BBC3 1px;
    border-bottom:solid #B6BBC3 1px;
    width:220px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 1px #F0F2F5;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 1px #F0F2F5;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 1px #F0F2F5;}

    .line-2{
     color:#808080;
     font-size:11px;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `clear: both;` with `display: inline-block;`

---

Also, did you declare a **doctype**? A doctype tells the browser what version of HTML you are using, so that the browser can render it correctly.

At the top of the page (Above the `<html>` tag) put:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This uses the HTML5 doctype, it allows for pretty flexible HTML code and should hopefully result in your page display correctly.

In HTML5, you can write markup in many different ways.
`<br>` is valid and so is `<br />` a new thing to HTML5 is that for an empty div you can actually use `<div id="emptyDiv" />` or `<div id="emptyDiv"></div>`

You can validate your HTML markup aswell.
**[The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)** is a free service that lets you upload your code or link to it and then run validation against it and print the errors/warnings. Some of the warnings are a little cryptic, especially for a beginner with HTML, but it's not the end of the world if you have a few warnings/errors any browser worth using will sort of 'figure it out' and render the HTML properly (it's called Quirksmode). Some of these validators are a bit more confusing/more complex than they should be to use, so you'll have to find the one you like most and stick with it.

Comment: Also for validating purposes declare doctype as shown here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Thanks, the only one not included there is the newer `<!doctype html>` but it's a good reference.

Comment: I did declared <!DOCTYPE html>, so it should be something else i guess

Comment: replace `clear: both;` with `display: inline-block;` in your css for `.line-1`

Answer (score 0):

Why does `.line1` have `float:left;` if you want TEXT1 on top of TEXT2? Looks like an issue to me.  Otherwise, .line2 needs to have `clear: both;` or something applied.